Difference between manually created RestTemplate, new RestTemplateBuilder & auto-configured RestTemplateBuilder
What is the difference between:

RestTemplate created with new:

var t = new RestTemplate();

RestTemplate created with the auto-configured RestTemplateBuilder

@Autowired
RestTemplateBuilder builder;

...
public void xyz() {
  var t = builder.build();
}


RestTemplate created from a new RestTemplateBuilder:

var t = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
According to
Spring Documentation:

Spring Boot does not provide any single auto-configured RestTemplate bean. It does, however, auto-configure a RestTemplateBuilder, which can be used to create RestTemplate instances when needed. The auto-configured RestTemplateBuilder ensures that sensible HttpMessageConverters and an appropriate ClientHttpRequestFactory are applied to RestTemplate instances.

But what are the additional HttpMessageConverters added?
And should #1 and #2 return RestTemplate with the exact same configuration?

TL;DR
#1 and #2 are not the same as 2 has extra pieces preconfigured for you. #1 and #3 are closer to the same but #3 has a few different configs.
Long Answer
The best way to see the difference is to look at the code of the autoconfiguration directly. Here is a link to the autoconfiguration code which I will copy below.
@AutoConfiguration(after = HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass(RestTemplate.class)
@Conditional(NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition.class)
public class RestTemplateAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer restTemplateBuilderConfigurer(
            ObjectProvider<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters,
            ObjectProvider<RestTemplateCustomizer> restTemplateCustomizers,
            ObjectProvider<RestTemplateRequestCustomizer<?>> restTemplateRequestCustomizers) {
        RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer configurer = new RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer();
        configurer.setHttpMessageConverters(messageConverters.getIfUnique());
        configurer.setRestTemplateCustomizers(restTemplateCustomizers.orderedStream().toList());
        configurer.setRestTemplateRequestCustomizers(restTemplateRequestCustomizers.orderedStream().toList());
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer restTemplateBuilderConfigurer) {
        RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        return restTemplateBuilderConfigurer.configure(builder);
    }

}

As you can see, it is just creating a new instance of RestTemplateBuilder and calling the configure method with configured customizers including the HttpMessageConverters, RestTemplateCustomizers, and RestTemplateRequestCustomizers.
As far as the difference between a new RestTemplate and the RestTemplateBuilder, if you take a look at the build method of the RestTemplateBuilder (link here) it just creates a new instance of RestTemplate and ultimately configures what was set on the builder so more or less they are the same.

Thanks. Is it possible to know exactly what additional converters/customisers they are adding to the autoconfigured one? I took a little more look in their source but couldn't understand. From the snippet you provided, I am just seeing it relying on messageConverters likely declared somewhere else?
Also, what should be the appropriate method for using RestTemplate? #1, #2, or #3?

Since the ObjectProviders are being used, any existing Beans that implement those interfaces would be added. There is a HttpMessageConvertersAutoconfiguration that would be used if you don't specify anything.

Personally I use #2 but with it preconfigured as a RestTemplate I can use directly.  You can see an example of how I do it here
